# How can I view SonarQube Web browser, Rule description and Issue Editor in Eclipse

Tags: java

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 lts, Os type 32-bit, SonarQube 4.5.2, Sonar-runner 2.4, java version "1.7.0_65", Eclipse Kepler.

While Analyzing SonarQube in Eclipse It shows the following Issue:

```
SonarQube Analysis has encountered a problem

Error during Execution of Sonar

Error during execution of Sonar
Error status [command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java -cp /tmp/sonar-runner-impl8404187497975734722.jar org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain /tmp/sonar-project6286406354288770628.properties]: 1



Retrieve remote issues of project SonarTest...
Start SonarQube analysis on SonarTest...
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create user cache/home/Username/.sonar/cache
    at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.createDir(FileCache.java:156)
    at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.<init>(FileCache.java:47)
    at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.create(FileCache.java:53)
    at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCacheBuilder.build(FileCacheBuilder.java:60)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars35.<init>(Jars35.java:40)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download35(JarDownloader.java:56)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:40)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory /home/Username/.sonar/cache
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:1748)
    at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.createDir(FileCache.java:154)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: what happened if you create the folder /home/<username>/.sonar/cache manually ?

Comment: I am not able to create folder "cache" manually in .sonar

Comment: there's something to find. If it's your home directory, why aren't you able to do that ?
And i think that the same reason the eclipse plug-in can't

Comment: Please tell me what is the next step?

Comment: Now i get /home/<username>/.sonar/cache manually

Comment: did you define SONAR_USER_HOME in your .bashrc ?
And then did you define sonar.userHome and sonar.working.directory in your  sonar-runner.properties.
What happened after you create the .sonar/cache manually? The error didn't change ?
And the most important question is, why sonarqube can't create the directory ? do you have write access to this directory ?

Comment: First of all .sonar folder is in lock and i open that lock.then i analyze the sonarqube in eclipse then i get cache file inside  .sonar folder.Now there is no error declared while analyzing sonarqube...but still i didn't get sonarqube web browser in eclipse.

Comment: i defined SONAR_USER_HOME and sonar-runner.properties

Comment: you didn't get sonarqube in eclipse but it works outside eclipse ? so may be there's a problem with the plugin version you use or something like that

Comment: yes you are right sonarqube works outside but not inside the eclipse.but in eclipse while analyzing sonarqube i get sonarqube issues,but not rule description,issue editor and web browser.

Comment: so for this problem, it will be hard to help you, try to follow docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse.